# Changed hwclock and system clock in linux virtual machine, now wants to revert my changes or come back to present

Tags: linux, time

for some testing , I changed the system clock and synced hardware clock to system clock using --systohc. Now , how to get back to current time?
I have already tried restarting machine.

when I untar a file , I get time stamp is in future.

Comment: Set the time manually to the 'correct time' and then sync the hardware clock as well. This could be done by using some global NTP Server, you could try this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-sync-your-linux-server-time-with-network-time-servers-ntp/) or also use this command in bash `cat </dev/tcp/time.nist.gov/13` to see the current time from NIST. Just a few ways to tackle your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used NTP server  to resync time on machine. Resync commands depend on OS being used.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the steps with the current time:

- set the system clock to the current time
- sync hardware clock to system clock: `hwclock --systohc`

How you set the system clock is up to you. Some options:

- Fetch current time via NTP: `ntpdate pool.ntp.org`
- Set current time manually: `date --set 09:11:16` (or whatever the time is - note this is time in the local timezone you use)